# What is the first line of the output of `ldd bash` and why is not required when setting a new root directory to use with chroot?

Tags: command-line, bash, chroot

I am following a tutorial about how to use chroot and set up a jailed dir.  The process is to copy bash and the libraries it depends on into the 'jail' dir.  To find the libraries bash depends on I use the comand:

```
ldd /usr/bin/bash
#which outputs
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd4cb6f000)
libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f11c0bb5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f11c098d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f11c0d5a000)
```

But whatever the first line of this output is, it is not required to be copied into the jail dir but all the files referenced on the other lines are.  I would like to know why?  And what is it?

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657036/where-is-linux-vdso-so-1-present-on-the-file-system  It's a virtual file the kernel exports.

Comment: You could also do what `man ldd` suggests and refer to `man 7 vdso`